# Python, Twitter Sentiment analysis

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nltk

i am getting this error upon running my code.

text = str(text.encode("utf-8"))
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'encode'

I tried to convert my data into string using df['Translated_message']=df['Translated_message'].values.astype('string')
but that doesnt worked.

Answer (score 0):

Text is a float. Check to cast as str before encoding.